# Can't assign dynamic key and value to object in reduce loop

Tags: typescript

I've been struggling understanding and resolving to these typescript errors ( I have spent a lot of hours on this). My pure javascript code worked very well. However I can't get typescript to cooperate.

I am assigning dynamic key values to properties on an object being built within a reduce function.

[I posted my code in a tsplayground so you can see the errors I receive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeSgHNMkEBnTGBCJOAbwCg5EATALjnJimSObhJMAW2CduvJPxbZaMHDAByAV2EAjNOJ58B2KsCLQAnlsnS4UAxVSXWAYQAWmXjCMr1mrtqkDMrVpbk5JyERACC-oHkvqzCyACq5J6hEXFIiWi6lvqsYTCmOizKYKw5eQU+AL6MjKCQsIgoaFi4BMQRAcBBDAIANsjAAIwV5pDcdhCsYl5muhDKKFAmM4Vw2AiuIwJColsyEMKiKFvVteDQ8Mg2LXgpsQlJUD0s6AhQ3Ioi0xKrvZgfXz2cGAwkwCF6JxqdQucFcYDwii6qFYAGlgEY4ABeOAAcj8nSCOLgAB9cX40hkoDizvVLk0MDg8ABleSoAAKUAgYHwagAVs84AA3TC9ZTfbzmNCcqBApBI4Co9EAfk4iO4CrRRgEMHm2AcCs4aggEF6wFIAic5AAolBpYbjabzdVoQ0rs1GXAAGLQYQs-QCnbTP3szncvkCSxEaxoBWOZwbNyqDQyuDB4Acrk83lzFAKdzJzhpjNh7MyfSGJaF1np0NZmIE4JwDpRGIUx6cVIPTIsCjeqDCABqIoQHDgRpNZqQjFOLrp1w9za65AF-Tlw1T1eLdZYYxgEymVf0W-D+wWPGWRdrJ7WCcPIcz18Dd5rD9LawOR3yG6PV7fcvVo7jo6U4zucrr0jcTb3OkjwCq87xKIC373iWfT-IhuzIS+qEsCCYIQlhx5-vKgEOpO05QmB8BwngbIQNwoQAEKTBi2L4HEMAADyhKQFBUDQSAADS4iORKkji2DZMieRibixSlNJMA4gAfDUjCyEg3BwEQwAwH2whspgRi9BAfhYnAAAU6A+mmnD6WmACUWLKQKlgwMoUB0FmwDYDAAB0ADW6LkFZNnVg5fm2MouCcXRDHEMxrBGMpFkWTg2DCUFRhOZiLlMCw+yafA1n9peXLmSVvrVgA2llcD-HAWUQOgXphfoAC6Ag9i1Fk0c1cCVWVYBYpi2I4kBk44k5bkeXQ6VdYgPU4v+yJEsgA1tShTn5QVLDpbV6L1cuTUtXFMBMSx7Xmd5vmBcFoWlZuoYRVFMV3A2JJtOE0GUilFkrQqYTYBlggkZqOV5Qtu0aVpYChhVm3YdVAOKhiDUnZZnYwWgn2LkEDmdbtu0IOgvVGPC-Vw+Vo1jRNpBTRYumzaDAFA9gUMFSTFk4sKorAGtdBU2A20c7tKNs8jYOHej6L9RZ71RJ9dxtmgBPmULfm82KosFTNnks9JwM69URO60z+vi0bpuVMJ9CVEdlnK12TykgrS4OQ5C2nMTS1a-zjQbY9P5ciLpv7XVMtGP1Z0XUlV3YoNT1cprIra7tJtm+5+vzSwNsMPbDUxwlLGe6cMPwGARkmWZ2I6XpPqGcZpmsBZO1PgKLB+5wOI-FIOKCQtUrQN3vdEP3C06tF+qjjwYoD7tlo2naA0ikkAg2xGVjqrYcYuImHgpjtnep9MPcSuPu1DymZ9mBfBWT3qBqwlAc8LYvtrDyvvRr7n8-vrmvl8yeCPkKE+I9z5-1wh-a+o874sAftPTgs9gCQLgO-ZeWBv7AHXn-PQqAKzLBAV3XEsDUFX3AbfVBCCn7INQegz+mCf5wA3ntSIS5OAgNXEMDhHNiE3z4HAgq5CSEQI5tQmeL8UEc3oSmRhUjTYo01N3fEURqTp1Qbufc0wQHHz5hQgRqCoHL34X3QxsJdSIOfq-U2MjOByLMYo9Eyi2GEi9qg2QZ5KwdwKnw0hHNhEmLHmY8RSDJFmNsV-JIDipbLDxC48gaiCosIKusTY3jdFin0aY-x0CslBLERYmhYTpH-CXgw1e8iiaONiSopciTf4LXbjo0BeiRGUJycYvxpsQlWMqQvUpuTIl9IKtU5xDZ6nMPcR+YAxx0ktMyW0gxHTP6BMEfAwpEjrFEwifYjmoyyTxImcklgKNQlp0ma2Z2PDdrwQBJhZpvjRGmwCV0omPTaElOtIM3ZCiYnOJVlSNxC0-h3O0bwsBizsnPMGas4JGyznDJYDsip0SAJKIOQCo5ZDQTgmuUTR57ToWdKeW8+FvTwkDIwSivZfyMXOyxY0kiCKcECF7D6Ic-RNnYMqJ7dStByATj8iZIgFlK5Nz8A5IAA).

Within my reduce functions in the `getFormPayload` function I created a few typeguards checking for a key that is a boolean value. The initial object looped through has this shape:

```
export interface FormState {
  name: StatePropObj
  registeredCharityNumber: StatePropObj
  contactNumber: StatePropObj
  category: StatePropObj
  address: Address
  adminUser: AdminUser
  isFormValid: boolean
}
```

I try to exit the loop for finding a boolean value for `isFormValid`. In additiona, the nested object `address` and `adminUser` need a nested reduce to format an object to return. The `address` and `adminUser` objects have a `nested` property which is a boolean value as well (I try to typeguard for this as well).

The goal is to create an object that I can send to the backend which is the `PostOrgBody` type:

```
export interface Organisation {
  id: string
  name: string
  contactNumber: string
  category: string
  registeredCharityNumber: string
  address: OrgAddress
  adminUser: OrgAdminUser
  createdAt: string
  updatedAt: string
}

export type PostOrgBody = Omit<Organisation, 'id' | 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt'>
```

However, I can't assign any values to the object I'm constructing. I also have a lot of keyof assertions and overall, I feel like I am missing something in my approach. It is embarassing to express how much time I've been trying to solve this. If anybody has any context to a better approach or how I can fix my current implementation I'm all ears. Thank you. Here is the code below (also you can reference the ts playground link above).

```
export interface Organisation {
  id: string
  name: string
  contactNumber: string
  category: string
  registeredCharityNumber: string
  address: OrgAddress
  adminUser: OrgAdminUser
  createdAt: string
  updatedAt: string
}

export interface OrgAddress {
  line1: string
  postCode: string
  country: string
  city: string
  name: string
  comment: string
}

export interface OrgAdminUser {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  email: string
}

export type NestedKey = 'address' | 'adminUser'
export interface StatePropObj {
  value: string
  error: string
  nestedKey?: NestedKey
  touched: boolean
  hasError: boolean
}
export interface FormState {
  name: StatePropObj
  registeredCharityNumber: StatePropObj
  contactNumber: StatePropObj
  category: StatePropObj
  address: Address
  adminUser: AdminUser
  isFormValid: boolean
}

export interface Address {
  line1: StatePropObj
  postCode: StatePropObj
  country: StatePropObj
  city: StatePropObj
  name: StatePropObj
  comment: StatePropObj
  nested: boolean
}

export interface AdminUser {
  firstName: StatePropObj
  lastName: StatePropObj
  email: StatePropObj
  nested: boolean
}

export type PostOrgBody = Omit<Organisation, 'id' | 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt'>


const getFormPayload = (formState: FormState) => {
  return Object.keys(formState).reduce<PostOrgBody>((acc, key) => {
    const formStateProp = formState[key as keyof FormState]
    if (typeof formStateProp === 'boolean') return acc
    if ('nested' in formStateProp) {
      acc[key as keyof PostOrgBody] = Object.keys(formStateProp).reduce<OrgAddress | OrgAdminUser>((nestedAcc, nestedKey) => {
        const prop = formStateProp[nestedKey as keyof (AdminUser | Address)]
        if(typeof prop === 'boolean') return nestedAcc
        if('value' in prop) {
          nestedAcc[nestedKey as keyof (OrgAddress | OrgAdminUser)] = prop.value
          return nestedAcc
        }
        return nestedAcc
      }, {} as (OrgAdminUser | OrgAddress))
    }

    if ('value' in formStateProp) {
      acc[key as keyof PostOrgBody] = formStateProp.value
    }
    return acc
  }, {} as PostOrgBody)
}

const payload = getFormPayload({
  name: {
    value: 'string',
    error: 'string',
    touched: true,
    hasError: false
  },
  registeredCharityNumber: {
    value: 'string',
    error: 'string',
    touched: true,
    hasError: false
  },
  contactNumber: {
    value: 'string',
    error: 'string',
    touched: true,
    hasError: false
  },
  category: {
    value: 'string',
    error: 'string',
    touched: true,
    hasError: false
  },
  address: {
    line1: {
      value: 'string',
      error: 'string',
      touched: true,
      hasError: false,
      nestedKey: 'address'
    },
    postCode: {
      value: 'string',
      error: 'string',
      touched: true,
      hasError: false,
      nestedKey: 'address'
    },
    country: {
      value: 'string',
      error: 'string',
      touched: true,
      hasError: false,
      nestedKey: 'address'
    },
    city: {
      value: 'string',
      error: 'string',
      touched: true,
      hasError: false,
      nestedKey: 'address'
    },
    name: {
      value: 'string',
      error: 'string',
      touched: true,
      hasError: false,
      nestedKey: 'address'
    },
    comment: {
      value: 'string',
      error: 'string',
      touched: true,
      hasError: false,
      nestedKey: 'address'
    },
    nested: true
  },
  adminUser: {
    firstName: {
      value: 'string',
      error: 'string',
      touched: true,
      hasError: false,
      nestedKey: 'adminUser'
    },
    lastName: {
      value: 'string',
      error: 'string',
      touched: true,
      hasError: false,
      nestedKey: 'adminUser'
    },
    email: {
      value: 'string',
      error: 'string',
      touched: true,
      hasError: false,
      nestedKey: 'adminUser'
    },
    nested: true
  },
  isFormValid: true
})

console.log(payload)
```

Comment: Is your goal here to get the compiler to *verify* that what you're doing is type safe? If so it might require a lot of refactoring involving generics and techniques from [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and frankly it seems too tedious to be worth it in Stack Overflow (unless you could pare down your example to be a bit more minimal so we can attack just a piece of it).  Or are you just trying to get the compiler to *allow* what you're doing without complaining (because you're sure you did it right)? If so then we can just throw assertions at it until it gives up.

Comment: (Aside: is there a reason your playground is using the relatively ancient TypeScript 3.8.3 instead of the current version TypeScript 4.9.5?)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ideally it would be type safe but getting the compiler to not complain would be a good start. 

3.8.3 is the version used in the app I'm working on.

Comment: So [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8494w) is the "assert ad nauseum" version.  If you want a more type safe version I probably won't touch it unless it's scaled down to a more manageable example (you could look at [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for the general issue, and ms/TS#47109 to see the kind of thing I'd have to do to make the compiler happy with the types; looks like two layers of that refactoring, which is a bit blah).  How would you like to proceed?

Comment: This was perfect and got me through a sticking point. I think I'll circle back after I have more experience with typescript and implement a more type safe approach. Thanks!